# Stop a loop if information is not found

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, break

I created a web scraping program that open several URLs, it checks which one of the URLs has information related to "tomorrow"s date and then it prints some specific information that is on that URL. My problem is that sometimes none of the URLs in that list has information concerning "tomorrow". So I would like that in such case, the program prints other innformation like "no data found". How could I accomplish that? Other doubt I have, do I need the while loop at the beginning?  Thanks.

My code is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = tomorrow.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

day = ""

while day != tomorrow:
    for url in list_urls:
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)
        dia_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='item2']/b").text
        dia_page = dia_page[-10:]
        day_uns = datetime.strptime(dia_page, "%d-%m-%Y")
        day = day_uns.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        if day == tomorrow:
            meals = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='item2']/span")
            meal_reg = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='item_frm']/span[1]").text
            sopa2 = (meals[0].text)
            refeicao2 = (meals[1].text)
            sobremesa2 = (meals[2].text)
            print(meal_reg)
            print(sopa2)
            print(refeicao2)
            print(sobremesa2)
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a `while` loop, you can use the [for-else](http://ncoghlan-devs-python-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html) Python construct for this:

```
for url in list_urls:
    # do stuff
    if day == tomorrow:
        # do and print stuff
        break
else: # break never encountered
    print("no data found")
```